# NTLM issue using node js as a proxy server

Tags: node.js, authentication, ntlm

Getting repeated NTLM prompts while using nodejs as a proxy to a share point site. 
We are using npm request module "var request = require('request');" and have found no solution after googling, Since NTLM uses tcp instead of http should we make any changes in code to get it working?

Comment: Tried by add https.agent for maintaining the socket connection but still its not working for me. whenever restart the server for the very first time its working perfectly but its not working for next request.